# Apache Wicket navbar set active after redirect

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I have the navbar menu at header. The header is used on every page.

Class hierarchy: `WebPage <- BasePage(includes new Header) <- Page...`

At navbar I have no whole web pages, but I need to active some `NavbarButton` if something is happend in body.

For example, there are two pages `Persons.html` and `AddPerson.html`, but one

```
NavbarButton button = new NavbarButton(Persons.class, Model.of("Persons")) {
        @Override
        public boolean isActive(final Component button) {
            if (button.getPage().getPageClass() == AddPerson.class) {
            }
            return super.isActive(button);
        }
```

I'd like to active button when `Persons.html` is choised as well as `AddPerson.html`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use Wicket-Bootstrap.
Use:

```
public boolean isActive(final Component button) {
  Class currentPageClass = button.getPage().getPageClass();
  if (Persons.class.equals(currentPageClass) || AddPerson.class.equals(currentPageClass)) {
     return true;
  }
  return super.isActive(button);
}
```

Comment: It is good solution, if button at navbar is alone. If there are more, than all will be activated, because true is returned.